# jQuery animate input value

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have this code I did, following a good idea from a stackoverflow user that recommended to use a color animation (if I use opacity, the entire field will vanish not only the value).

```
$(function(){
    /* Hide form input values on focus*/ 
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        var txtval = $(this).val();
            $(this).focus(function(){
                if($(this).val() == txtval){
                    $(this).val('').animate({"color":"#3c444e"},500);
                    }
            });
        /*Restoring value if blur*/ 
        $(this).blur(function(){
            if($(this).val() == ""){
                $(this).val(txtval).animate({"color":"#ffffff"}, 500);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The code is animating properly but only on the blur function not on the focus, I suppose it's because I'm changing the value to '' to fast to animate, but that should also apply to the blur function so I'm confused.

Anyway to make the animation work on focus as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($(this).val() == txtval){
    $(this).animate({"color":"#3c444e"},500, function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Pawel_W I have an extra issue now :) when field fades off what user types is not visible. I have to see how to solved that